# The type arguments for method cannot be inferred from the usage TModel, TProperty

Tags: c#, generics, type-inference

```
public class Test { public int Id { get; set; } }
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var model = new Test { Id = 222 };
        Helpers.TestMethod(m => model.Id); // doesn't work
        Helpers.TestMethod<Test, int>(m => model.Id); // works
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public class Helpers
{
    public static string TestMethod<TModel, TProperty>(Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression)
    {
        // Do some work on expression
        return string.Empty;
    }
}
```

If I were using @Html.TextBoxFor extension method. I don't have to specify the Types like this: @Html.TextBoxFor, Why is this? Why do I have to explicitly specify the Types?

Comment: Why are you trying to call it with two arguments when the method only has one parameter? (I can't see how the second version compiles...) A short but complete program demonstrating the problem would really help...

Comment: I copied the code and the second parameter has nothing to do with the question. I removed the second param. Thanks for down voting for no reason!

Comment: The types cannot be inferred if there is nothing to infer from.  In `TestMethod(m => model.Id);` there is nothing that can be used as a clue to infer the type of `Test` for TModel.

Comment: So how do you expect the compiler to figure out that the first generic argument should be `Test`?  Why shouldn't it be `string` or `int` or `SomeOtherType`?

Comment: m = TModel in intellisense. So what do you mean?

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for `TestMethod<TProperty>(Expression<Func<TProperty>> expression)`, to be called as `TestMethod(() => model.Id)`, but for what you have now, it makes perfect sense that it doesn't work.

Comment: You have no idea whether I downvoted the question or not... But it's lazy to give an example which is broken like that. You claim that the second parameter was irrelevant, but if you don't know what the problem is, how can you know... Unless you remove it consistently, in which case that is the code to post.

Comment: How is it possible to infer Model for Html.TextBoxFor?? When I never specified Html.TextBoxFor<Test, int>.

Comment: @JasonFoglia Because there's something to infer it *from*. To be precise, the type of `Html` is what it can be inferred from.

Comment: @JonSkeet your not wrong in saying that the code was broke. But the error and the question had nothing to do with the second param.

Comment: @JasonFoglia But until you give us sensible code *we can't know that*.  For all we knew there was another overload that you were trying to call that used the type you were trying to infer, thus making the whole process rather sensible.  Now we at least have a better understanding of why you're code is broken, whereas before there were multiple ambiguous possible explanations for what you were doing wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How is it possible to infer `Model` for `Html.TextBoxFor`?? When I never specified `Html.TextBoxFor<Test, int>`.

If you look at how `TextBoxFor` is implemented, you'll see that it's an extension method:

```
public static MvcHtmlString TextBoxFor<TModel, TProperty>(
    this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
    Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression
)
```

`htmlHelper` is used to infer `TModel`, and that's exactly what your method is missing.

```
public static string TestMethod<TModel, TProperty>(TModel model, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression)
```

now you can call it without specifying generic types:

```
var model = new Test { Id = 222 };
TestMethod(model, m => m.Id); // works just fine
```

You can also make it an extension method, adding `this` modifier

```
public static string TestMethod<TModel, TProperty>(this TModel model, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression)
```

which would allow you to call it

```
var model = new Test { Id = 222 };
model.TestMethod(m => m.Id);
```

Comment: Thank you so much @MarcinJuraszek!!! It didn't appear to me that HtmlHelper<TModel> was the problem. Thank you again!